# Click on object is not registred

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I can't find what I did wrong because when I click on triangle object on canvas value of e.target is false. For other type of objects (lines,circles...) "objectname" gets its value.

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
    if (e.target) {
        objectname = e.target.name;
    }
});
```

What must I check  or can You pleas instruct me how to proceed debug this mistake?

I had a suspect that "selectable=false;" or "deactivateAll();" might be the cause of this trouble and I did  text search, but nothing did come out.

Next is a photo of objects. I can click on any object except triangle and i will get name of objects.
 [objects on canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7tAK.jpg)

I don't need new code which will get me name of objects on canvas. My code snippet is working for all objects except triangle. It is that i have made some confusion with code for triangle objects. And now mouse:down is not registered when i click on triangle. And i can't debug this.
That's the problem.

I will ask in other way, what must i do to prevent on  mouse:down event to trigger when clicking on particular object to fire?

Because it is obvious that i did that with triangles because now i have this problem.

Next is an better example.

```
 canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
         if (e.target) {
               console.log('e.target is: '+e.target.type);
         }else {console.log('e.target is null ';}
    }
```

By clicking on any object except triangle I get e.target.type.
And i did check all objects for objects[i].selectable and i did get true in all cases (even for triangles).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am using fabrics.js library.

Comment: besides fabric, are you using jQuery? Because `.on()` is a jQuery function

Comment: Yes. It works fine for other objects. I did something to prevent click on triangle to be registered.

Comment: And by the way what did I wrong to get -1?

Comment: I don't need code which will get me name of objects on canvas. My code snippet is working.  It is that i have made  some confusion with triangle object settings. And now mouse:down is not  registered when i click on triangle. And i can't debug this. (I have added also photo of objects on canvas to my question)

Comment: It is called Fabric.js, not Fabrics.js

Comment: you can create a snippet/jsfiddle with all your code, I guess your triangle is not selectable thats why `mouse:down` is not firing.

Comment: var triangleAngle;

Comment: I have find the solution thanks to to example on code snippet page. Thank you. It is many times impossible to  send part of code with trouble, because 
 code can be large. so with code testing snippets you have to analize existing code. And as in my case it can bring you to solution. Change var triangleAngle to  var triangleAngle=0 in next code fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u8v4n0dg/ and and triangles will become selectable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using jQuery because of the `.on()` function, you can get the `name` of the canvas this way, binding the click with `.on('click', function(){...}`

```js
var canvas = $('#myCanvas');
canvas.on('click', function(e) {      
   if (e.target) {    
          objectname = $(e.target).attr('name');
          console.log(objectname);
   }
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" name="This is my canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer in plain vanilla JavaScript:

```
// Initialize a compatibility test
var compatibilityTest = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

// Update the test
compatibilityTest = (
    typeof compatibilityTest == 'function' &&
    compatibilityTest.toString().indexOf('[native function]') > -1
);

// Compatible function for legacy and modern browsers
function setEvent() {
    var args = [... arguments].slice(1),
        element = arguments[0];

    EventTarget.prototype[
        compatibilityTest ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent'
    ].apply(
        element,
        ((compatibilityTest ? '' : 'on') + String(args[0])].concat(args.slice(1))
    )
}

// Set the event
setEvent(canvas, 'click', function listener(event) { /* Do something... */ })
```